# How to write linq query for select ID from list of list?

Tags: c#, linq

How to write linq query for select ID from list of list?
I have following List: `SearchingDataList`,in this list again contains another list that is
called `SearchDataList` and in this list contains an `ID` field.

How do i Select that particular `ID` while I select `selectedItem` from a `ListBox`?

The structure is like this:

```
SearchingDataList.SearchDataList.ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = OuterList.Where(t=>t.InnerList.Any(s=>s.Id == yourID));
```

Comment: Thank You.but i want to fetch ID of selected Item from List.And I bind these list to ListBox.How to Select that selected Item ID from List?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear.

This way you get a list of all ids in the the nested list.

```
searchindDataLists.SelectMany(x => x.searchDataList).Select(x => x.Id)
```

Comment: Thank You.but i want to fetch ID of selected Item from List.And I bind these list to ListBox.How to Select that selected Item ID from List?